# using command on a gnplot script

Tags: bash, gnuplot

Im using a script on a mac bash shell that uses gnuplot.

When I use

```
using 1:($2*100.0)
```

on the script, I get

```
using 1: (*100.0)
 line 0: invalid expression
```

However, if I use the same command on the gnuplot prompt line I have no problems.

Is there a different format for the `using` command when using it on a script?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you post your script?

Comment: most likely the proper solution here is to not put your gnuplot commands in a bash script at all.  Create a gnuplot script as a separate file and invoke 'gnuplot gnuscript' from your bash shell/script.   Please show a complete script if you need further help with this..

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't posted your script, I can only guess.

The problem may come from the fact that $2 is interpreted by bash as "the second argument of the script".  You should escape the dollar sign with a backslash.

```
using 1:(\$2*100.0)
```

Comment: Thank you gawi, that was it! Strange though that when running gnuplot you still have to specify that. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2193037 -- It's not really strange at all -- Bash does the substitution before passing the commands to gnuplot.  It doesn't care at all what program you're passing the string to.  As a side note, if this solved your problem, you should consider accepting it as the answer by clicking the little checkmark next to it.